# Wordpress and houzz save button

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In a wordpress site I add a houzz save to idea book button and when it opens the pictures do not appear. If I set it to a specific img only that one shows up when you click save no matter what img in the gallery you are one and I need it to work on any img. I am using the following code part was from houzz. [Clemens - Gallery](http://clemenspantuso.com/?project=italianate-riverside-home-chagrin-falls-ohio)

```
<div class="houzz-share-button">
<a class="houzz-share-button" data-url="http://www.houzz.com/pro/rpantuso/clemens-pantuso-architecture" 
    data-hzid="34137" data-locale="en-US" 
    data-img="$("a.houzz-share-button").attr("data-img", src);"
    data-title="CLEMENS PANTUSO Architecture" 
    data-desc="" data-category="" data-showcount="0"
    href="https://www.houzz.com">Houzz</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data-img = $("ul.slides li:first-child img"); // grab the image
        var src = $(img).attr("src"); // get the img source
        $("a.houzz-share-button").attr("data-img", src); // set in link
    });
</script>
```